# Multithread on oracle sequence. Is it possible that thread will get same sequence value from other thread?

Tags: multithreading, oracle, sequence

Just a simple case. I need to insert 40 million records into table A. Every insert statement, i'll use sequence object to stored. Example :

```
insert into table A ( objId,name,location ) values ( objId.nextval, ?,?);
```

instead of im doing normal looping to insert this table A, can i make a multithread for this kind insertion command? could be the objId value will be use sharing with other thread? can be the thread will get the same value with other thread?

Purposely is i want make this process more faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point of sequences are to generate unique numbers in a multiuser system.  You could (if your database didn't collapse first) have a million simultaneous sessions each running the `INSERT` statement 40 times and you'd get 40 million distinct numbers.

That being said, if you're trying to load 40 million rows of data, running an `INSERT` 40 million times would not be my first choice particularly if you're not planning on batching the statement calls.  Doing a direct-path load of 40 million rows with a single `INSERT` is likely to be much more efficient.

Comment: "Doing a direct-path load of 40 million rows with a single INSERT is likely to be much more efficient." can you give some example? do you mean by load/import script like using sqlplus or using the insert select statement?

Comment: @Sh4m - It depends on how you are receiving the data.  It might be a SQL*Loader load if you've got a flat file of data to load.  It might be a single `INSERT ... SELECT` if the data is coming from a different relational database.  Your client API may expose a direct-path mode for the load as well (though that's harder the more database agnostic the API tries to be).